# Running PowerShell script that runs exe as prebuild step in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

In my Visual Studio Pre-built command line I have a newly created line

`Powershell.exe -file "$(SolutionDir)Folder1\MyPowerShell.ps1"`

And in this PowerShell script, it runs an .exe with some parameters

`.\MyProgram.exe .\SomeFileArg.xml`

When I run just the PowerShell script locally, either as `./MyPowerShell.ps1` or copy pasting the command into my PowerShell, it works.

But when I build my Visual Studio, this doesn't occur. I get the error `.\MyProgram.exe.exe : The term '.\MyProgram.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,  2>  function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the  2>  path is correct and try again.` If I include the absolute path instead in my PowerShell script, then it works.

How can I achieve this with local paths? Or is there a variable so I don't have to hardcode the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the local path (where the script file resides) as a variable in your code using:

$PSScriptRoot

https://riptutorial.com/powershell/example/27231/-psscriptroot

Comment: Would I instead be calling it like

$PSScriptRoot\MyProgram.exe $PSScriptRoot\SomeFileArg.xml?

Comment: No, not exactly, you will want to add the strings together to get what you want. Let me show you an example:

https://imgur.com/a/nqj670U

Comment: I got it to work, thanks!

I saved the whole string command into a variable and executed it with invoke-expression.